# Angular ngOptions and filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter an array on ngOptions:

Here a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OxL84mDdma9iS13wMnIX?p=preview

I have this array:

```
  $scope.keys = [  { 
                id: 1,
                name: 'ddddggggggggggggggggg',
                applicationKey: 'dssssssssssssss',
                kind: 'pingdom',
               } ,  { 
                id: 2,
                name: 'Ddd',
                kind: 'moz',
                accessId: 'ssss',
                secretKey: 'aaaa',
               } ,  { 
                id: 3,
                name: 'MyAlexa',
                kind: 'alexa',
                secretAccessKey: 'ssssssssssssssssss',
                accessKeyId: 'ssssssss',

               }
            ]
```

And I'm trying to filter using somethig like this:

```
    <select name="key" ng-model="keys" 
      ng-options="k.name for k in keys track by k.id | filter: {kind: 'alexa'}" >
    </select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can filter out a value like this. You can only change its formatting but removing the value would be done on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to do the following:

```
<select name="key"
        data-ng-model="keys" 
        data-ng-options="key.name for key.name in keys | filter: { kind: 'alexa' } track by key.id">
</select>
```

You must have the `track by` after you apply the filter.

**EDIT**:

The only issue you had in your markup is the `track by` expression being before the filter. The rest of differences are just personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<select name="key" ng-model="keys" 
          ng-options="k.name for k in keys  | filter: {kind: 'alexa'}" >
        </select>
```